# Proper way to send an Authenticity Token with AJAX to Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authenticity-token

This works but gets stopped because it lacks an authenticity token:

```
$(".ajax-referral").click(function(){
  $.ajax({type: "POST", url: $(this).parent("form").attr("action"), dataType: "script"});
  return false;
});
```

So I tried adding it like so:

```
$(".ajax-referral").click(function(){
  $.ajax({type: "POST", url: $(this).parent("form").attr("action") + "?&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN, dataType: "script"});
  return false;
});
```

And it passes the auth_token correctly as a param, but seems to lose the rest of my form.

Anyways to accomplish both sending the form data that works, and the authenticity token as well?

This is a rails environment. And I have this in my head.

```
= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = '#{form_authenticity_token}';" if protect_against_forgery?
```

**Things I've tried**

1.

```
= hidden_field :authenticity_token, :value => form_authenticity_token
```

2.

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: $(this).parent("form").attr("action"), dataType: "script", authenticity_token: AUTH_TOKEN});
```

3.

```
// Always send the authenticity_token with ajax
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    if ( settings.type != 'GET' ) {
        settings.data = (settings.data ? settings.data + "&" : "")
            + "authenticity_token=" + encodeURIComponent( AUTH_TOKEN );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, you are reading the `action` attribute of form and sending a post ajax request to it. to send form data you have to submit the form or you can serialize the form data and send it in ajax request like

```
$(".ajax-referral").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: $(this).parent("form").attr("action") + "?&authenticity_token=" + AUTH_TOKEN, 
      data:$(this).parent("form").serialize(),
      dataType: "script"
      });
  return false;
});
```

Doing this will serialize your form data and send it along with ajax request and authenticity token is already being sent via query string

Comment: I had to use encodeURIComponent( AUTH_TOKEN ), but using it in the query string worked once I did this.

Comment: token should not be sent in the url!

Comment: @Gacci unless your endpoint URL is http (i.e. plain-text), the params (`authenticity_token` in this case) will _also_ be encrypted. So I'd rather say "token should always be sent to httpS URLs". Ajax-called URLs are not kept in browser history anyway.

Answer (score 34):

This token also already appears in one of the "meta" tags in the head of the application.html.erb layout file by default if you have the following ERB at the top:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

That ERB roughly renders to:

```
<meta content="abc123blahblahauthenticitytoken" name="csrf-token">
```

You can then grab it using jQuery with the following code:

```
var AUTH_TOKEN = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
```

Comment: may not be possible in rails 5 as each form get his own auth token https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/11/per-form-csrf-token-in-rails-5.html

Comment: Good point, @FabrizioBertoglio I think this comment was written around Rails 3/Rails 4 days.  May not be possible to do it this way in later versions.

Answer (score 34):

None of these worked for me until I set the `X-CSRF-Token` value on the request header via JS like this:

```
request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
```

`token` of course, being the CSRF token. I got this from the `<meta name="csrf-token">` tag and did not use `encodeURIComponent()`

**Update** since this is proving useful to some

So all in all:

```
var token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
```

Comment: This is the solution for Rails 5+ with the gotcha that [`per_form_csrf_tokens` must be set](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/11/per-form-csrf-token-in-rails-5.html) for Single Page Application situations.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks!

Just to clarify for the more common use.

You need the js tag with var AUTH_TOKEN in your head. Should be something like this.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<%= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = '#{form_authenticity_token}';" if protect_against_forgery? %>
```

And then simply put your authenticity_token=AUTH_TOKEN in the ajax data if you don't need to use parent(form) or something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  dataType:'text',
  data: "user_id="+user_id+"&authenticity_token="+AUTH_TOKEN,
  url:'/follow/unfollow'
})
```

Thanks to the guys above for sharing this knowledge!

Comment: The auth token is base64 encoded. It may contain a plus sign (+). If you don't properly escape the auth token, rails will parse it as a space, because of url encoding.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5.1+ a CSRF token is automatically appended if you use a built-in `Rails` JS helper for AJAX requests(from `rails-ujs`), example:

```
Rails.ajax({
  url: "/your/url",
  type: "POST",
  data: "a=1&b=2",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

This library also provides you a helper to get CSRF token manually if you need it with:

```
Rails.csrfToken();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could include the AUTH_TOKEN in the form itself, as a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="AUTH_TOKEN">1234abcd</input>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value={$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')}/>`  (Note that I'm using JSX for templating.   Replace the `{` with whatever's appropriate for your template language.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue but I tried this approach in my application.js file:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  if (options.data == null) {
    options.data = {};
  }
  options.data['authenticity_token'] = token;
});
```

This is the original question where I got the idea: [ajaxSend Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332305/modifying-a-jquery-ajax-request-intercepted-via-ajaxsend)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that applies to all AJAX requests.
You add the following to your all.js (or whatever your sitewide javascript file is)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrftoken"]').content
    }
});
```

This will automatically add the token as a header on all AJAX requests.  Works for me in Rails 7.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using form_tag automatically includes CSRF token parameter. Rails supports "Unobtrusive Javascript" meaning that the form will still be submitted via AJAX. Controller actions support "respond_to" block, and you can use .js.erb extension to make changes on the web page in response to form submit.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted here for including the CSRFToken did not work for me, using Rails 6.1.  Here is what works now.

```
csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrftoken']").getAttribute("content"); 

fetch("your_action_path", {
               method: 'POST',
               headers:  {
               "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(your data for your post)    });
```