# Ajax PUT request results in logout in Rails app. Why?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, session, csrf, logout

2 places in [my Rails app](http://www.club-mst3k.com) have ajax calls.
(one for jQueryUI drag-and-drop sorting, and one for updating a comment post).

Whenever these calls occur, the user gets logged out. For no apparent reason.
I'm using omniauth-facebook and omniauth-google-oauth2 for authentication.

How can this get fixed?

Here's what the ajax call looks like (coffeescript):

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    data: {post_id: post.attr("id")},
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: -> post.children('.headpost').children('.buttons').removeClass('new_reply'),
    url: '/posts/update/'})
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails/

Okay, the session gets reset because my ajax request doesn't have the authenticity token. Now, how to do that with an ajax request in an assets coffeescript file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

In application.html.erb layout head, under `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`:

```
<%= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = '#{form_authenticity_token}';" if protect_against_forgery?%>
```

In assets/whatever.js.coffee

```
$.ajax ({
            type: 'put',
            data: {authenticity_token: AUTH_TOKEN},
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: -> post.children('.headpost').children('.buttons').removeClass('new_reply'),
            url: '/posts/'+post.attr("id").slice(5) });
```

Comment: thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560837/proper-way-to-send-an-authenticity-token-with-ajax