# Why does my 'POST' request NOT call my method, even though it sends something?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, post

I'm trying to request a 'POST' for a Controller Method which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: something, data: {to_find_id: 978636122}, success:function(){ }});
```

It sends my Data, which shows the following log:

```
Started POST "/thingys/519716477/do_something" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 14:54:44 +0200
Processing by ThingysController#do_something as */*
  Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"978636122", "thingy_id"=>"519716477"}
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 702273327]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

A short explanation of `302 Found`:
[WIKIPEDIA-LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

My method:

```
def do_something
  Something.create(timespan_id: params[:to_find_id].to_s, thingy_id: @thingy.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :nothting => true}
  end
end
```

I've allready defined my method in my `routes.rb`-file.

```
resources :thingys do
  post 'do_something'
  post 'undo_something'
end
```

So it sends the request, even finds the method.

Do you know, what can I do, to make it work?

---

EDIT:

I've added my Authenticity Token, but I still can't access my method.

```
Here is what I get now:
Started POST "/thingys/519716477/add_something?&authenticity_token=1l3tTWfwNgt56lp93w2QghUJvUYZn87V/8Zs7Fcrijq+8=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-07 13:04:15 +0200
Processing by ThingysController#add_something as */*
  Parameters: {"to_find_id"=>"310026847", "authenticity_token"=>"1l3tTWfwNgt56lp93w2QghUJvUYZn87V/8Zs7Fcrijq 8=", "subgroup_id"=>"519716477"}
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.5ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 702273327]]
  ←[1m←[36mThingyp Load (0.5ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "subgroups".* FROM "thingys" WHERE "thingys"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", "519716477"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

---

I have also added `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in my ApplicationController and `skip_before_filter:verify_authenticity_token` in my ThingysController.

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Answer (score 1):

you cant send POST param in rails without authenticity token in rails.

Refer to the CSRF Countermeasure in this page : 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

or to this thread
[Understanding the Rails Authenticity Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token)

Comment: How do I send the authenticity token to my app with my Ajax request?

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560837/proper-way-to-send-an-authenticity-token-with-ajax

Comment: Thank you, I allready got my Authenticity-Code, but it still does not work. I've put the new log it into my EDIT

Comment: did you add 'protect_from_forgery secret: "your code" ' in the called controller?

Comment: I added it in my ApplicationController and use skip_before_filter:verify_authenticity_token in my ThingysController

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "doesn't work" means the action is not preforming that task you expect, which would be the creation of a `Something` instance.  If I had to guess, that something is failing to pass the validations defined on the model. This will prevent the model from saving.

You can try: `Something.create!(attrs)` instead, which will raise an error if validations fail, making it clearer why it's not saving.

To get it to work, you just need to save a valid `Something`, whatever that means to your application.

---

You also have a typo

```
format.js {render :nothting => true}
#                      ^ typo!
```

Comment: Hello Alex,
thank you for your fast response, It does not do anything. I've tried to add some code, to see, if it calls the method, like adding a line with `puts "-----IT WORKS-----"` into my method, but it does not print it. So it does not execute my method.