# Session destroyed when POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, sinatra

I have a POST method in Sinatra:

```
post '/api/:token/boards/:identifier' do
    user = session[params[:token]]
    {:user=>user}.to_json
end'
```

If a do POST to this URI I receive null, and my userAccount is logged-out.
If I try the same method with GET I receive my username.

```
get '/api/:token/boards/:identifier' do
    user = session[params[:token]]
    {:user=>user}.to_json
end'
```

Where is the problem?

**Note:** I have session enabled in config.ru

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, "super_secret"
```

Comment: I feel like something checks a form authenticity token

Comment: This answer might help as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/14136067/699147

Comment: Can you paste the POST and GET requests? I believe that :token is probably empty causing your user to be set to nil.