# Is it possible to set multiple base URLs in a single HTML file?

Tags: html, ajax

I have an HTML file that contains breadcrumb links and a Javascript file that fires AJAX calls.

The breadcrumb links are relative to the HTML page. The AJAX calls are relative to the webapp context-path.

So for example, if the current HTML page is http://host.com/context_path/companies/5/user/10/index.html (where "5" and "10" are arbitrary IDs I don't know ahead of time):

- I need to generate breadcrumb links to http://host.com/context_path/companies/5/
- I need to fire AJAX calls to http://host.com/context_path/

If I set `<base href="http://host.com/context_path/">` then the AJAX calls work fine, but I have no way of resolving the breadcrumb links relative to the HTML page.

**Is there any way for me to implement this using client-side relative links?** Or am I forced to resolve the links on the server side?

Comment: Having to separate `base` elements is not possible (and I’d consider even one bad enough, since I found they usually create more problems than they solve). Any reason why can’t you just simply specify the _correct_ path, either absolute or relative?

Comment: @CBroe: I don't see how I can set the correct path using *client-side* resolution. I've updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: Why not? _You_ are outputting those relative links after all, so where is the problem in changing `wrong/relative/path` to `correct/relative/path` …? Totally unclear to me how that could be a problem. (Unless maybe you never handled relative paths correctly before, because you always relied on the `base` element … which one shouldn’t do IMHO, as I already said.)

Comment: @CBroe, the HTML file in question is a static file returned by different URLs. The server is **not** rewriting its contents depending on which company id was referenced. If I set `<base>` to the context path, then I am forced to specify the company id as part of the relative path (since `<base>` stripped it off), but I have no way of doing this because the HTML file is static. If I could specify paths relative to the original location, then a relative path of `../../` would return the correct URL regardless of the company id. I hope you now understand what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

While it is true that the `<base>` tag affects all relative links, it looks like `location.href` points to the original HTML page [1]. So what you can do is set the `<base>` tag to satisfy the AJAX calls, and set the breadcrumb links relative to `location.href` using Javascript code.

[1] While I can't find any mention of this in the HTML specification, it seems to hold true for Chrome 34.0.1847.137m.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. As specified in MDN:

> Usage Note: If multiple  elements are specified, only the first href and first target value are used; all others are ignored.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Looks like the only way is to use javascript to convert your AJAX urls to full ones. There may be a way with `$.ajax` that allows you to intercept AJAX requests and manipulate the url before the request is made.

[Modifying a jQuery ajax request intercepted via ajaxSend()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332305/modifying-a-jquery-ajax-request-intercepted-via-ajaxsend) may be a good starting point